# Guards for a Raven Queen Temple

Tags: dnd-4e, monsters, adventure-writing

I have a party of four 3rd level adventurers.  They will be breaking into a temple dedicated to the worship of the Raven Queen.  There will be a ritual taking place in the sublevels of the temple.  I am wanting the party to encounter some defensive constructs or mobs before they reach the ritual.  Does anyone have suggestions as to the sort of mobs that would be used by Raven Queen clerics to defend their temple?

Comment: Raven-shaped flesh/bone golem? (Not that I have any ideas what stats it should have.)

Comment: I think that was the basis of the D&D game that was played in the chatroom here once, If I remember correctly :)  In that game it was protected by Paladins for the Raven Queen.

Comment: Zombie Kenku that moan "Winter is coming"... Don't hit me!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Her domains are *Death*, *Fate*, and *Winter*.

So aside from the obvious raven iconography, consider the **vultures** who "hold no pity for those who suffer and die, for death is the natural end of life."

She is prayed to during funeral rites, so consider **fire elementals** flavored as funeral pyres.

Perhaps **chain golems**, **chain guardians**, and other such constructs are manifestations of her admonishment not to "cast off the chains of fate".

As a Winter Queen, she probably has access to **elementals and constructs of ice, cold, snow, and blizzards**.

@SevenSidedDie makes a good point: although undeath is abhorrent to the Deathly Queen, her realm is certainly filled with the physical evidences of it. Perhaps appropriately-shaped (ravens?) **bone golems**, **bone constructs**, and similar beings would not offend her?

....Of course, there's always the generic animated statue route, just flavor the statues appropriately.

[I am assuming that the standard paladin/priest/warrior/etc dedicated to Her Holy Darkness are obvious and need not be expanded upon, as you mentioned her clerics in the question.]